# Rebuild static library for a different architecture

Tags: swift, portability, tvos

Is it possible to rebuild a static library (.a) for a different architecture?
For example in an tvOS app I have this warning:

> building for tvOS, but linking in object file built for iOS, for
>   architecture arm64

I do not have the source code of the library.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, yes. If you have only the object file, no.

Ask the vendor of the library to provide you with the binaries you need.